# Setting up default input device in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound, python, python3, microphone

I'm writing a program to take voice input from the built in microphone and then print the received voice on screen. My program is as follows :

```
import speech_recognition as sr

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Speak Anything :")
    audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print("You said : {}".format(text))
    except:
        print("Sorry could not recognize what you said")
```

but I'm getting the error as follows  :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "text.py", line 4, in <module>
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
  File "/home/ashish/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 86, in __init__
    device_info = audio.get_device_info_by_index(device_index) if device_index is not None else audio.get_default_input_device_info()
  File "/home/ashish/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyaudio.py", line 949, in get_default_input_device_info
    device_index = pa.get_default_input_device()
OSError: No Default Input Device Available
```